# How to use one hot encoder on categorical data in scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following array (actually a Panda data-frame which has an array-like data structure) that is similar to the following:

```
[
   ['M', 4, 15]
   ['M', 3, 7]
   ['F', 5, 9]
   ['I', 4, 15]
]
```

I wish to preprocess this data so I can use it in linear regression.
I believe the way to do this is by using one hot encoder: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.

However, that only works if the categories are integers.

I believe you can do this using a `DictVectorizer`: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer

However, this only seems to work for dictionaries, not arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your categories to integers with code similar to the following:

```
def tokenize(data, col_of_category):
    str_to_int, int_to_str = {}, {}
    for row in data:
        cat = row[col_of_category]
        if cat in str_to_int.keys(): token = str_to_int[cat]
        else:
            token = len(str_to_int.keys())
            str_to_int[cat] = token
            int_to_str[token] = cat
        row[col_of_category] = token # assuming your rows are mutable
    return str_to_int, int_to_str
```

You can then use the returned dictionaries to manage mapping and unmapping in the future. You can then just use the `OneHotEncoder`. Your algorithm doesn't care that there are strings involved.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your dataframe `df` is this:

```
>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    M     4    15
1    M     3     7
2    F     5     9
3    I     4    15
```

For converting `col1` into one-hot encoded vector, you can use the pandas `get_dummies` method.

```
>>> df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['col1'])
>>> df
   col2  col3  col1_F  col1_I  col1_M
0     4    15       0       0       1
1     3     7       0       0       1
2     5     9       1       0       0
3     4    15       0       1       0
```